# Filling Ember selection with data received from server

Tags: ember.js

I would like to receive json data from server and then generate html selection tag in Ember. This is my handlebars template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="rankings">
  {{view Ember.Select contentBinding="countries" optionLabelPath="countries.name" optionValuePath="countries.path"}}
</script>
```

and my Ember trunk

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter;

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('rankings')
});

App.RankingsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('countries', this.store.findAll('country'));
  }
});

App.RankingsController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    countries: []
});

App.Country = DS.Model.extend({  
    path: DS.attr('string'),  
    name: DS.attr('string'),
}
```

It is not working fine. I am not having any errors in console and template is not rendering with this route and controller. What can be wrong?

Comment: Are you actually hitting the rankings route? /#/rankings

Answer (score 1):

Ember.Select looks for data on your controller's model.  You have the countries array set up outside of your content, so it will not be able to view the data.

Personally, I would do it in the following way, though there are a couple of different approaches you can take to get similar results:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter;

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('rankings')
});

App.RankingsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {countries : this.store.findAll('country')};
  }
});

App.RankingsController = Ember.Controller.extend({
});

App.Country = DS.Model.extend({  
    path: DS.attr('string'),  
    name: DS.attr('string'),
}
```

Comment: The main problem was that I haven't created model. Although, everytime when I hit the page, data is loading from server again. There is not any cache. I am going to use this data on serval controllers, so I would be nice to have it preloaded. Anyway, I didn't check yet your approche. I hope that it will be better than mine. Thanks.